# Git remove files in current directory only

Tags: git

I have a directory of text files that I want to remove from git. But there are also folders in the directory that also have text files that I want to keep.

If I run `git rm *.txt` I get rid of about a hundred text files in the current directory. But also the subdirectories (that also have text files) are deleted.

How can I remove JUST the text files in the current directory, but leave the text files in the subdirectories unaffected?

ok, I am using git on Windows 10. I start off with [this directory](https://imagebin.ca/v/4mc4eFUgyQsz), I have a subdirectory that [looks like this](https://imagebin.ca/v/4mc5i7vkkBHW), and if I give the git rm ./*.txt command [that directory and others](https://imagebin.ca/v/4mc6HighCWYk) disappear along with the text files in this directory.

I am using the powershell command line to do this.

Comment: Same thing happens. I also get rid of subdirectories that have text files using that command.

Comment: So not only the text files are removed, but the entire directory is removed?

Comment: yes the entire subdirectories that also contain .txt files are also removed. Basically all of the text files in the current directory and the subdirectories that have .txts are removed.

Comment: That is not the behaviour I see when running the same commands. What OS/shell/version of git are you using?

Comment: ok, I am using git on Windows 10. I start off with this [directory](https://imagebin.ca/v/4mc4eFUgyQsz), I have a subdirectory that looks like [this](https://imagebin.ca/v/4mc5i7vkkBHW), and if I give the `git rm ./*.txt` command that [directory and others](https://imagebin.ca/v/4mc6HighCWYk) disappear along with the text files in this directory. Hopefully that's clear! lmk if I can provide any other info. Thx!

Comment: @Gimby, no the directories themselves are not named ending in .txt. The directories that go missing have .txt files in them, but they themselves are not named .txt

Comment: Unable to reproduce; behaves as expected in my tests

Comment: I tried `git rm *.txt` and it worked as expected on both Windows and Ubuntu. Only the text files in the current folder were removed.

Comment: Surely Git has nothing to do with the glob expansion, the shell does that?

Comment: I can reproduce the issue with `git rm \*.txt` or `git rm ./\*.txt`. And you can find an example `git rm Documentation/\*.txt` in `git rm` document. I thought you were using git bash. Now I find that you are using `cmd`. It can be reproduced in `cmd`.

Comment: I suggest you use `git-bash` instead. Commands and their options may have kinds of problems in `cmd` and `powershell`.

Comment: Well... I partially agree with @ElpieKay that git bash is easier to use with git.  But, from the observations above (which I've now confirmed in my own tests), this does SEEM like a bug.  The reason we all thought it was working as expected was because bash was pre-expanding the wildcard in our test - which actually wouldn't happen in some circumstances.  The behavior around paths with both a directory and filename does not seem to conform to documentation when `-r` is not provided.

Comment: ok, it works as expected using git bash. But when I use the powershell command line it produces the unwanted result in the OP. So it may be a bug in the git code as it interacts with the powershell command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm), providing the directory name will only remove the files in that directory.

- `git rm ./*.txt`

Providing the directory name, requires explicitly passing the `-r` flag for recursively going into sub-directories.

---

**Update**: the OP clarified that the command was being run in Windows PowerShell, and evidently the above command does not work as expected in PowerShell.  It should work using `Git Bash`.

Comment: The subdirectories that have text files also disappear when I use that command. I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: it works as you describe when I use git bash. However the issue is when I use the powershell command line. I think I will stick to git bash for now. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0):

My most recent tests agree with what you're describing - that in spite of the docs, if you give a path with a leading directory and a wildcarded filename, it matches recursively even without the `-r` option.

I've found two work-arounds:

One is to remove the files in CMD and then stage the deletions as a separate step

```
del *.txt
git add *.txt
```

This is often ok, but may be a problem if you mean to use `git rm --cached`.

The other is to abuse the shell's glob expansion.  This happens by default in `bash` or similar shells, which is why a lot of us never notice this behavior; but it isn't really an option in CMD as far as I know.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of going through pages of Git documentation you can use typical command line utilities. On unix systems (or in Git Bash/Cygwin):

```
cd folder
rm *.txt
git add -u
```

Comment: Using a command deliberately added to git is not "abusing" git.

Comment: It actually is. The tool is bloated with extra commands that weren't required. Using tools that were created for removal is better than adding this possibility (and complicating documentation and code) to each utility that works with files.